# PHPSTAN Binary operation "*" between string and 3600 results in an error

Tags: php, phpstan

I am trying to run easy function for converting longitude and latitude from decimals to DMS.

```
    $vars = explode(".", $dec);
    $deg = $vars[0];
    $tempma = '0.' . $vars[1];

    $tempma = $tempma * 3600;
    $min = floor($tempma / 60);
    $sec = $tempma - ($min * 60);

    return $deg . '°' . $min . "'" . $sec .'"';
```

When I upload it on gitLab, phpstan is reporting an error:

**Binary operation " * " between string and 3600 results in an error.**

Can anyone help me how to solve this problem?

Comment: What sort of value is in `$dec`?

Comment: I am using string

Answer (score 0):

Try with a cast before

```
$to_be_cast = '0.' . $vars[1];
$tempa = floatval($to_be_cast);
```